# Using Idris to Model State Machine of Open-Close Door

Tags: state-machine, idris

At ScalaWorld 2015, Edwin Brady gave an exciting talk on Idris - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X36ye-1x_HQ.

In one of the examples, I recall that he showed how to use Idris to write a program representing a Finite State Machine (FSM) - for opening and closing a door. His
FSM may be a bit more complex, but, given the following states:

```
data DoorState = DOpen | DClosed

data DoorAction = Open | Close
```

I wrote a function that, given a `DoorAction` and `DoorState`, returns the new `DoorState`.

```
runDoorOp : DoorAction -> DoorState -> DoorState
runDoorOp Close DOpen  = DClosed
runDoorOp Open DClosed = DOpen
```

But, the above function is partial, example: `runDoorOp Open DOpen` would crash.

I thought of using an `Either` or `Maybe` data type, but I think (from hearing that talk) that it's possible to encode this FSM in a type-safe way without `Either/Maybe`.

What's the idiomatic, Idris way to write the above function using path-dependent types, not using `Maybe/Either`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I encode and enforce legal FSM state transitions with a type system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059650/how-can-i-encode-and-enforce-legal-fsm-state-transitions-with-a-type-system)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common strategy to represent these finite state machines is to define the states as an enumeration (which is precisely what your `DoorState` does!)

```
data DoorState = DOpen | DClosed
```

And then describe the valid transitions by defining a relation (think: `DoorAction a b` means that from `a` I'm allowed to go to `b`). As you can see the *indices* of the constructor `Open` are enforcing that you may only open a door if it's currently `Dclosed` and it'll become `DOpen`.

```
data DoorAction : DoorState -> DoorState -> Type where
  Open  : DoorAction DClosed DOpen
  Close : DoorAction DOpen   DClosed
```

From there on you can describe well-formed sequences of interactions with a door by making sure that whenever you try to apply an action, it is allowed by the state the system is in:

```
data Interaction : DoorState -> DoorState -> Type where
  Nil  : Interaction a a
  Cons : DoorAction a b -> Interaction b c -> Interaction a c
```

In Edwin's talk the situation is more complex: the actions on the door are seen as side effects, opening the door may fail (and so it's not necessarily true that we have `Open  : DoorAction DClosed DOpen`) but the core ideas are the same.

An interesting article you may want to have a look at is McBride's [Kleisli arrows of outrageous fortune](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf). In it, he is dealing with the same sort of systems equipped with an internal finite state machine in Haskell.

Comment: As I was reminded by @user3237465 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059650/how-can-i-encode-and-enforce-legal-fsm-state-transitions-with-a-type-system/32085128#32085128)'s comment section, this domino-esque structure of your `Interaction` type is [already available in the Agda standard library](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Star.agda) and as such, it might be useful as inspiration for an Idris implementation.

Comment: I leaved a comment, but for some reason it has disappeared. Attempt number two: With your version you'd write `ex₁ : Interaction DClosed DClosed; ex₂ : Interaction DOpen DClosed; ex₂ = Cons Close ex₁`, which is very counterintuitive to me: you have an interaction from `DClosed` to `DClosed` and you prepend one more `Close`. I'd define `Cons` as `Cons : DoorAction b c -> Interaction a b -> Interaction a c`. Then `ex₂ : Interaction DClosed DOpen; ex₂ = Cons Open ex₁`.

Comment: @user3237465: that comment was removed because I went and fixed that typo in gallais's answer.

Comment: @Cactus, only the first sentence was about the typo. The rest of the comment was about `Cons : DoorAction a b -> ...` vs `Cons : DoorAction b c -> ...`.

Comment: @user3237465 oops, OK I got you now. Why not just edit the answer? (And change it to `Snoc` to make it even better, maybe?)

Comment: @Cactus, that's a too big change. It also needs to be described and I don't want to mess other people's answers with my nasty english. Yes, I should have called it `Snoc` or maybe something infix with the parameters flipped.

Comment: It should be noted that snoc (or the more general `(++)`) can be defined.

Comment: Confused as to whether any type could *inhabit* the `Type` in `data DoorAction : ...`, I replaced `Close : DoorAction DOpen DClosed` with `Close : DoorAction DOpen Int` - note that I replaced `DClosed` with `Int` - and it failed to compile! Why's that?

Comment: Because the indices need to be of the type `DoorState` as specified by the annotation `data DoorAction : DoorState -> DoorState -> Type where`

Comment: I attempted to create an instance of `Interaction` with: `Cons Hw1.Open Nil`, but got `Can't infer argument c to Cons, Can't infer argument c to []`. Why?